# How to manage lifetime through callbacks

Tags: rust, callback, lifetime

I'm trying to create a function that, given a callback, it can perform some operations on a string and, in case that it requires some modifications, returns a new allocated copy. I'm using **std::borow::Cow** for such a thing but the problem comes when I try to use a callback to change how that operation over the string is performed.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;
pub enum Error {
    Test,
}

fn do_lower_case<'a> (s: &'a str) -> Result<Cow<'a, str>, Error>
{   
    let s = s.to_lowercase();
    Ok(s.into())
}

fn say_hello<'a>(
    f: impl Fn(&'a str) -> Result<Cow<'a, str>, Error>,
) -> Result<Cow<'a, str>, Error> 
{   
    let s = String::from("Hello");

    // Problem: We can not call the callback from here.
    // Nevertheless we can call do_lower_case
    let s = f(&s)?; // Comment this and uncomment next line works
    //let s = do_lower_case(&s)?;

    let s = s.into_owned();
    Ok(s.into())
}

fn main() {
    let res = say_hello(do_lower_case); // Callback is provided here
    match res {
        Ok(s) => println!("Result: {}", s),
        Err(_) => println!("Could not do anything!"),
    }
}
```

Can something like that be done in Rust?
Here is a link to a rust playground:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8607d8ac4c34d02236e82e30bcf51e2e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler complains, because the lifetime of `s` is always shorter, than the lifetime that can be provided by `'a`.

To work around that, you can use [higher-ranked lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds). Instead of a generic lifetime in the `say_hello` function, you'd specify one that only applies to the closure. This is done by adding `for<'a>` in between `impl` and `Fn`. After that, `say_hello` cannot return `Cow<'a, str>` either, and would need to return `String`.

```rust
fn say_hello(f: impl for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> Result<Cow<'a, str>, Error>) -> Result<String, Error> {
    let s = "Hello";
    let s = f(&s)?;
    let s = s.into_owned();
    Ok(s)
}
```

Alternatively, the following might be more readable:

```rust
fn say_hello<F>(f: F) -> Result<String, Error>
where
    F: for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> Result<Cow<'a, str>, Error>,
{
    let s = "Hello";
    let s = f(&s)?;
    let s = s.into_owned();
    Ok(s)
}
```

*Changed `let s = String::from("Hello");` to `let s = "Hello";` as well.*

---

In this case, you can also rely on [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) and optionally use the placeholder lifetime `'_`. Then it becomes:

```rust
fn say_hello<F>(f: F) -> Result<String, Error>
where
    F: Fn(&str) -> Result<Cow<str>, Error>,
{
```

or

```rust
fn say_hello<F>(f: F) -> Result<String, Error>
where
    F: Fn(&'_ str) -> Result<Cow<'_, str>, Error>,
{
```

*You can also inline either one using `impl Fn...` as you originally had.*